# Wrap long string in Python IDLE

Tags: python-idle

The string I am writing is very long. To make it easier to read, I would like to wrap the text onto multiple lines. How is this done?

Comment: The content of the string doesn't have any relevance on the question. In the IDE for Python, the shell and the interactive sheet have the same problem. Put simply, if you type a very long piece of text, it disappears off the side of the page, unlike this comment box where it wraps the text around into many lines. If you use the return key to wrap the text, instead of starting a new line, it runs the program. Hoping someone knows how to wrap the text without executing the line of text.

Comment: Are you talking about inputting a long line of text or outputting a long line of text?  The answers are quite different for the two cases.

Comment: Hi. On the input side please. Most of the script is no longer than 40 characters however, the dictionary item is near 250 characters and very hard to edit as over half of it is off the page.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[This answer applies to Python in general and is not specific to IDLE.]

For input of long strings without embedded newlines, you could enter a multiline string and then delete the newlines.  But if you want lines to end with spaces after commas and periods, you will not see them and they will disappear if you strip line-ending whitespace from your code.  (This is required for CPython stdlib code.)

An alternative is to use Python's [string literal concatenation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation) feature.  White space is guarded by line-ending quotes, and comments can be added.  (See the link for another example.)

```
stories = {
    'John' : "One day John went to the store to buy a game.  "  # the lead
        "The name of the game was Super Blaster.  "  # the hint
        "On the way to the store, John was blasted by a purple ray.  "
        "The ray of purple light, mixed with super neutrinos, "
        "came from a alien spaceship hovering above."
    }

import textwrap
print('\n'.join(textwrap.wrap(stories['John'])))

# prints

One day John went to the store to buy a game.  The name of the game
was Super Blaster.  On the way to the store, John was blasted by a
purple ray.  The ray of purple light, mixed with super neutrinos, came
from a alien spaceship hovering above.
```

Comment: Hi all. I uncovered the correct method to manipulate the length of the input such as a dictionary in Python where the line length ii so far past the edge of the page width that you can do longer see the functions etc.

Comment: To start a new line to keep the text compact. Use space, plus sign space and finally \ . The backslash will start a new line

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on IDLE in the top left corner
2. Select Settings
3. Select Keys
4. Locate 'newline-and-indent'
5. Select Get New Keys for Selection
6. Enter a shortkey of your choosing